# usage of ternary operator

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

below is simple ternary operator.

```
 hc.colspan= ( hc.colspan == 1 && hierarchycount == 0) ? hc.colspan : hc.colspan +1
```

I need to make this more simple instead of assigning the same value to hc.colspan when the condition is true.

How can I do this without assigning same value to hc.colspan when the condition is true.

like consider another example

```
a = a!=0 ? a : b
```

Above we are assigning same a value to "a" again when the condition comes to true. But I don't want to assign it again. How can I do this in a different manner?

Comment: I don't see a `if-else` part of this operation. This is just a `if` case !!!

Comment: `a = (a != 0 ? a : b)` is an attempt of putting `if` into one line. It's up to you decide which one is better, but I am pretty sure compiler can *remove* unnecessary `a = a` assignment. So question is: why do you care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to remove the ternary operator and go with a normal `if` statement:

```
if(!(hc.colspan == 1 && hierarchycount == 0)){
    hc.colspan += 1;
}
```

or, inversed per MarkO's suggestion:

```
if(hc.colspan != 1 || hierarchycount != 0){
    hc.colspan += 1;
}
```

Comment: i saw some where in C# to avoid this kind of same assignments.but i forget the concept thats what am expecting from ...

Comment: You're being rather unclear; where do you see the "same assignment"?

Comment: @SivaRajini Why make an easy thing complicated? Just use an `if`

Comment: @jeroen am not saying same assignment. if you want to assign same value back to the variable no need to write

Comment: @Jeroen, may I suggest to inverse the condition?

Comment: @Magnus thanks.we can write above conditions in so many ways. but what am expecting to avoid assigning same value to same variable, C# have some concept, thats what am expecting.

Comment: @MarkO: added the inverse because it is indeed easier to read.

Comment: @Marko i had seen some where in SO itself  about my problem but now i can't get correct link to proceed.

Comment: @SivaRajini Yes, its called an `if`

Comment: @SivaRajini Maybe you mean ?? operator (null-coalescing). But it's not good in this case.

Comment: *avoid assigning same value to same variable* Where do you see the same value being assigned to the same variable (although it's already rather unclear what this means)? Can you tell us exactly what part of the code doesn't sit right with you?

Comment: @SivaRajini What is your problem? Your ternary operator example indeed has the useless assignment of a variable value to itself. The solution Jeroen provided is the right answer.

Comment: @2GDev Great man. that is the concept am thinking about. thanks

Comment: @Marko nothing dude. i am searching (null-coalescing) concept (see 2GDev comment) that why lot of confusions.

Comment: @Jeroen Thank you very much am going to use your solution.this one looks good

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
if(!(hc.colspan == 1 && hierarchycount == 0))
     hc.colspan++;
```

Comment: no this is not correct.when conditio true means i dont want to increase

Comment: ok, simple not operator will do it for you. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 0):

For your first example you could do this:

```
hc.colspan += (hc.colspan == 1 && hierarchycount == 0) ? 0 : 1;
```

But generally, if you only want to change the value in one case, just use an `if` clause.

Comment: am expecting some other conept in C#. is there is only way ?

Comment: For conditional assignments you have only the ternary operator or an `if-else` clause.